# Google Speech API returning time offsets for wrong words

Tags: google-speech-api

I have a node function that takes in an audio file recorded on a mobile device and returns the transcription and time offsets for each word in the transcription. Everything seems to be working well except that the time offsets seem to be associated with the wrong words.

Here is my function:

```
const speech = require('@google-cloud/speech');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const path = require('path');
const os = require('os');
const fs = require('fs');
const ffmpegPath = require('@ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg').path;
const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');

admin.initializeApp();

export const transcribeAudio = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    const { name, fullPath } = req.query;
    const bucket = admin.storage().bucket('audio-test.appspot.com');
    const tempFilePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), name);
    const targetTempFilePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), `${name}-converted.mp3`);
    await bucket.file(fullPath).download({ destination: tempFilePath }).catch(console.warn);
    const command = ffmpeg(tempFilePath)
        .setFfmpegPath(ffmpegPath)
        .format('mp3')
        .output(targetTempFilePath);
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => command.on('end', resolve).on('error', reject).run()).catch(console.warn);
    const file = fs.readFileSync(targetTempFilePath);
    const audioBytes = file.toString('base64');
    const audio = { content: audioBytes };
    const client = new speech.SpeechClient();
    const config = {
        encoding: 'MP3',
        sampleRateHertz: 16000,
        languageCode: 'en-US',
        enableWordTimeOffsets: true,
        enableAutomaticPunctuation: true,
    };
    const request = {
        audio: audio,
        config: config,
    };
    const [response] = await client.recognize(request).catch(console.warn);
    res.send(response);
    fs.unlinkSync(tempFilePath);
    fs.unlinkSync(targetTempFilePath);
});
```

And here is the json returned from that function:

```
  {
    "results": Array [
      Object {
        "alternatives": Array [
          Object {
            "confidence": 0.9800227284431458,
            "transcript": "How much wood would a woodchuck chuck if a woodchuck could chuck wood?",
            "words": Array [
              Object {
                "endTime": Object {
                  "nanos": 100000000,
                  "seconds": "4",
                },
                "speakerTag": 0,
                "startTime": Object {
                  "nanos": 700000000,
                  "seconds": "3",
                },
                "word": "How",
              },
              Object {
                "endTime": Object {
                  "nanos": 400000000,
                  "seconds": "4",
                },
                "speakerTag": 0,
                "startTime": Object {
                  "nanos": 100000000,
                  "seconds": "4",
                },
                "word": "much",
              },
              Object {
                "endTime": Object {
                  "nanos": 700000000,
                  "seconds": "4",
                },
                "speakerTag": 0,
                "startTime": Object {
                  "nanos": 400000000,
                  "seconds": "4",
                },
                "word": "wood",
              },
              Object {
                "endTime": Object {
                  "nanos": 800000000,
                  "seconds": "4",
                },
                "speakerTag": 0,
                "startTime": Object {
                  "nanos": 700000000,
                  "seconds": "4",
                },
                "word": "would",
              },
              Object {
                "endTime": Object {
                  "nanos": 0,
                  "seconds": "5",
                },
                "speakerTag": 0,
                "startTime": Object {
                  "nanos": 800000000,
                  "seconds": "4",
                },
                "word": "a",
              },
              Object {
                "endTime": Object {
                  "nanos": 100000000,
                  "seconds": "5",
                },
                "speakerTag": 0,
                "startTime": Object {
                  "nanos": 0,
                  "seconds": "5",
                },
                "word": "woodchuck",
              },
              Object {
                "endTime": Object {
                  "nanos": 600000000,
                  "seconds": "5",
                },
                "speakerTag": 0,
                "startTime": Object {
                  "nanos": 100000000,
                  "seconds": "5",
                },
                "word": "chuck",
              },
              Object {
                "endTime": Object {
                  "nanos": 200000000,
                  "seconds": "6",
                },
                "speakerTag": 0,
                "startTime": Object {
                  "nanos": 600000000,
                  "seconds": "5",
                },
                "word": "if",
              },
              Object {
                "endTime": Object {
                  "nanos": 400000000,
                  "seconds": "6",
                },
                "speakerTag": 0,
                "startTime": Object {
                  "nanos": 200000000,
                  "seconds": "6",
                },
                "word": "a",
              },
              Object {
                "endTime": Object {
                  "nanos": 700000000,
                  "seconds": "6",
                },
                "speakerTag": 0,
                "startTime": Object {
                  "nanos": 400000000,
                  "seconds": "6",
                },
                "word": "woodchuck",
              },
              Object {
                "endTime": Object {
                  "nanos": 0,
                  "seconds": "9",
                },
                "speakerTag": 0,
                "startTime": Object {
                  "nanos": 700000000,
                  "seconds": "6",
                },
                "word": "could",
              },
              Object {
                "endTime": Object {
                  "nanos": 200000000,
                  "seconds": "9",
                },
                "speakerTag": 0,
                "startTime": Object {
                  "nanos": 0,
                  "seconds": "9",
                },
                "word": "chuck",
              },
              Object {
                "endTime": Object {
                  "nanos": 600000000,
                  "seconds": "9",
                },
                "speakerTag": 0,
                "startTime": Object {
                  "nanos": 200000000,
                  "seconds": "9",
                },
                "word": "wood?",
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
        "channelTag": 0,
      },
    ],
  }
```

In the above example, I intentionally dragged out the word "woodchuck" the 2nd time I said it. If you look at the offsets, it seems like the times for that word were applied to the following word, "could," which I said much more quickly in the recording. Any insight as to why this would be happening would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Did you file an issue on https://github.com/googleapis? To me it's obviously a bug. My guess is that multiple passes are used to transcribe. The 1st pass may find word boundaries. The 2nd may do a dictionary compare. Possibly a 3rd does a phrase check for common phrases - though I know you can send you own phrases to check.

Comment: @JohnPankowicz Thanks for that insight! I filed an issue as you suggested.